# ssis flat file on weekly but execute one by one

Tags: ssis

We have  15 to 20 table  which we get  the data from flat file  from Monday to Friday. We have  4 master packages each master  have 12 to 30 packages   We have  to execute all in Saturday according some condition,
Monday files   to  be execute first from  flat file table  to  all the master packages  then Tuesday how to do  that  if I use for each loop it loop all the files  then move to master. Result effect the data
Motive is to make batch table that show Monday file execute,    execute date  Saturday
similarly  to    Tuesday  show Tuesday  file execute,    execute date  Saturday

Answer (score 0):

two ideas:

1. You can use multiple foreach loops and chain them together so that they go in a certain order.   Each one is filtered to only process the files that you want to process at that stage (first loop is only Monday files, second loop Tuesday files, etc).
2. You can do everything with a script task.

Comment: i consider that there are 5 foreach loop first foreach(monday) loop execute first from RAW  to DW means all the master  packages  executed then  Tuesday. it  make possible that there is Holiday in client  and has not send the file Wednesday then ?

Comment: Then the Weds loop would not have any file to process and you would move on to the Thursday loop.